# How to remove action query window after delete action in search phpmyadin 404

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

After doing a search and delete records button it performs the delete and takes me to a query window showing the delete query that I just did.  In the future this always showed up at the bottom of the page and I could continue delete from the search.
Can you tell me how to either disable this query window or keep it at the bottom so I don't have to search after every delete? I suspect it's something about a refresh.

Comment: This is about version 4.0.4, correct? and are you talking about table search or database search (I guess it's database search).

Comment: Yes 4.0.4  When I table search and it shows me the results I use the delete and it takes me to a query (window) instead of refresh and window at the bottom.  I have to go back to delete the rest of the fields and it still shows the fields in search window that I deleted.